# Determine required object type from uninitialized object

Tags: java, android, object, null, android-view

I would like my code to help determine what object type is required automatically.

**Background:**

The code to attach a widget is often as follows:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

I want to then check that textView has been found correctly in order to avoid bugs. To do this, I'm using a custom (AttachWidgetException) exception:

```
if(textView == null) throw new AttachWidgetException(name);
```

**Idea:**

Rather than having to repeat these two lines for every widget in my code (DRY), I decided to make a function to simplify it. I incorrectly assumed I could do this:

```
public View attachWidget(View view, int resID, String name) throws AttachWidgetException {
    view = (view.getClass) findViewById(resID);

    if(view == null) throw new AttachWidgetException(name);
    return view;
}
```

Called from within a *Try* block by:

```
 TextView textView = attachWidget(textView, R.id.textView, "textView");
```

**Problem:**

But, this doesn't work for two reasons. The caller's object is expecting a TextView not a View. I think the other reason is *view* is yet to be instantiated and therefore  is reported as:

```
java.lang.Class <capture<? extends android.view.View>
```

… which is not an extension of View. To fix this, I need to change the line in attachWidget to:

```
view = findViewById(resID);
```

...and the calling line to:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) attachWidget(textView, R.id.textView, "textView");
```

… which makes the View input parameter useless. We can remove that at this point.

**Question:**

This really isn't too bad, but is there a way to do this so I don't need to manually add the cast? Can *attachWidget* automatically determine that it needs to return a TextView? I'm pretty sure I'm heading in the wrong direction of any possible solutions. Would generics help me in any way here?

Please forgive me if I am using incorrect terminology in my description. I would appreciate any code / terminology / methodology corrections.

Comment: Looks like reinventing the wheel - do you know [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)?

Comment: @mjn Thanks for your reply. Actually, I don't want to use any external libraries. Perhaps I should have specified that in my original question. I was more interested in learning if Java had the facilities to do this. It seems like a fairly simple problem. I just need to tell the attachWidget function to convert to a known type. Renan's answer is actually pretty close to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `view.getClass` when view is `null`. Try doing this:

```
public <T extends View> T attachWidget(Class<T> type, int resID, String name) throws AttachWidgetException {
        View view = findViewById(resID);
        if (view == null) throw new AttachWidgetException(name);
    try {
        return type.cast(view);  
    } catch (ClassCastException) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new AttachWidgetException(name);
    } 
}
```

In this case, you can call like:

```
TextView textView = attachWidget(TextView.class, R.id.textView, "textView");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I changed the top line to add T as a return type. My compiler complains that view instance of T is always going to be true when reached. It won't compile for this reason. Actually, class or array instead of T is expected (in that same area) is the reason it won't compile.

Comment: Okay, I've got most of this working now. Thank you for the Class<T> bit - I had no idea about that. My caller now looks like -- textView = attachWidget(TextView.class, R.id.textView, "textView"); -- and I had to remove the or, ||, section of the code for it to work. Is there anyway to fix that || segment?

Comment: Instead of the || section, I put the return type.cast(view) in a try/catch block. So now it reports if it can't find or can't cast the View. This seems like a pretty clean solution. If you could update your code with my changes / suggest any improvements, I think that'd make your answer a good choice for acceptance.

Comment: This looks good. I'll double check the code when I get home and accept your answer if it works as we think it will. Thank you.

Comment: Your code won't detect if the view returns null. Find the view. Then do an 'if null - exception', then add the try catch block. Remove the NullPointerException. Remove the final return null section (it will never reach there), And also, your final throw is missing a semi-colon. Fix all that, and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Great. Thank you for your help. Your code didn't compile as it was missing an object name for the ClassCastException. I edited your answer, but I'm not sure if they will allow it. I also added e.printStackTrack.